# Compare change score across groups VS relation between pre score and change score

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have some data of pre/post structure of about N = 100 subjects. 
Some training is given, and the same tests are given before and after the training on knowledge and attitudes about some subject matter. In pretest survey, additionally demographics and other information of the training participants are collected. The participants of the training may not be randomly selected, but most likely because they received the news of the training and came.

Given how the data was collected (which is probably not the best for any inferential tests), the goal is to compare the change in the test scoresamong different groups of the participants (call factor X), it seems ANOVA (or T, if groups level is 2). But I also did some analysis of change score (Y2 - Y1) against pretest score (Y1), and found Pearson's rho = -0.8, p<0.00001.

So I am wondering when Y1 is found to be significantly different (or not) across groups formed by factor X(through ANOVA or T test), how should I make of the test results of ANOVA (or T) of Y2-Y1 across X?

For example, my age group is formed by quartiles of age, so I have almsot balanced groups. Normality of residuals, and homogeneity of variances are checked. The usual ANOVA F (not the Welch's F) is used. Follow up paired comparisons found say age group 1 has significantly higher pretest score than age group 2, but change score is not, though overall F for change score is significant. Is there something to be said about certain age group do not have significant change even though their pretest score is significantly lower? B/C overall, the relation between pretest and change is so strong?